# 3D Rigid Registration - Minimal Points Analytic Solution - How to Build Rotation Matrices?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, registration, algebra

I have two sets of three (non-collinear) points, in three dimensions. I know the correspondence between the points - i.e. set 1 is {A, B, C} and set 2 is {A', B', C'}.

I want to find the combination of translation and rotation that will transform A' to A, B' to B, and C' to C. Note: There is no scaling involved. (I know this for certain, although I am curious about how to handle it if it did exist.)

I found what looks like a [solid explanation](https://docs.google.com/open?id=1o_uafQmeRKi4A2lAbMJPeo-BSnUSHBp4nJb6PLaHo8NvQWvaFQXD5qIFy8x4) while trying to work out how to do this. Section 2 (page 3) entitled "Three Point Registration" appears to be what I need to do. I understand steps 1 through 4 and 6 through 7 just fine, but 5 has me stumped.

```
5. Build the rotation matrices for both point sets:
    Rl = [xl, yl, zl], Rr = [xr, yr, zr]
```

How do I do that???

Later I plan to implement a least squares solution, but I want to do this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this document](http://www.cs.hunter.cuny.edu/~ioannis/registerpts_allen_notes.pdf) appears to have an identical copy of that section, but following that is a **worked example**.  i must admit that it's still not clear to me how the step works, but you may find it clearer than me.

update: column 1 of Rl is the x axis constructed earlier ([0,1,0] in terms of the original axes).  so i imagine that x, y and z are the axes, as column vectors.  which makes sense...  and i assume Rr is the same in the other coordinate system.

is that clear?

Comment: Worked example ftw! Thank you, that does indeed make sense. (And yes, Rr is the same in the other co-ordinate system.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it.

each point gets an equation: a_1x + b_1y + c_1z = d_1, right, so make 2 3x3 matrices of the 
a,b,c values.

then, since each point is independent of one another, you can solve for the transform between the two matrices, A and A'

T A = A'
After some linear algebra,

T = A' inv(A)

Try it in MATLAB and let us know.

Comment: I just tried in MATLAB and it worked for me with dummy points and a scale and rotation combined. Registration refers to aligning two images typically and involves more than just solving for a transform.Usually an image is moved around wrt to a reference and a cost function is applied.

Comment: This solves for a linear map from A to A'.  For 3 points such a map always exists.  But a linear map is not the same as Rotation + Translation: it has no translation component.  It may also contain reflection, shear, stretching, etc.

Comment: Affine transforms are linear because they use the extra row of 0 0 1, forgot what this is called. A 9 degree transform, scale, rot and  translation has an inverse, only the shear breaks that. An affine transform has 12 dof and that's all. Reflection is rotation.